# rake resque:work ignoring QUEUE flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, resque

The command `bundle exec rake QUEUE=metrics_queue BACKGROUND=yes resque:work` executes successfully and spawns a new worker, but the worker is not set to the specified queue.

```
$ bundle exec rake QUEUE=this_string_does_not_matter BACKGROUND=yes resque:work
$ ps aux | grep resque
ubuntu   104137     17:22   0:00 resque-1.27.4: Waiting for add_queue,metrics_queue
```

From the console:

```
2.3.0 :001 > Resque.workers
=> [#<Worker ip-x:102760:metrics_queue>,#<Worker ip-x:104094:add_queue>,#<Worker ip-x:104137:*>]
2.3.0 :002 > Resque.workers[-1]
=> #<Worker ip-x:104137:*>
2.3.0 :003 > _.queues
=> ["metrics_queue", "add_queue"]
```

The list of queues for this worker is also sometimes empty.

Running the same command from another directory on the server works as expected, that's how the other workers got there. But the resque config is the same in both directories as far as I can tell. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Came back to this problem and found a workaround: use QUEUES instead of QUEUE. No idea why QUEUE was not working for a single queue.